# How to know the location of a function being compiled by the compiler

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, glibc

I am trying to modify glibc to use with my program. I wanted to add some code to the mmap function (Not the mmap system call, but the function in glibc which performs the mmap system call). However, I see several mmap or mmap64.c files inside the source code directory.

My architecture is x86-64, so I ignored the files in other architectures's directory. However, I have no idea the mmap from which file the compiler is using. I intentionally inserted some garbage code (So that compiler gives an error), in different files containing the mmap function, but the compiler compiles glibc fine without giving any error. I can even see the .o files created. I have no idea what to do know. Any easy way to determine which mmap the compiler is compiling?

Answer (score 2):

> Any easy way to determine which mmap the compiler is compiling?

```
gdb -q libc.so.6

Reading symbols from /tmp/build/libc.so.6...done.
(gdb) list mmap
76  #else
77  
78  /* This is a "normal" system call stub: if there is an error,
79     it returns -1 and sets errno.  */
80  
81  T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
82      ret
83  T_PSEUDO_END (SYSCALL_SYMBOL)
84  
85  #endif
(gdb) info source
Current source file is ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
Compilation directory is /glibc-git-rw/glibc/misc
Located in /glibc-git-rw/glibc/sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S <<< You want this
Contains 87 lines.
Source language is asm.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

Comment: When I type list mmap, gdb says No symbol table is loaded. Use the file command.

Comment: @user1018562 "No symbol table loaded" -- don't run GDB on installed `libc.so.6` (which doesn't have debug info). Run it on the copy you just built.

Comment: Well, I compiled with the -O2 optimization. I think I should pass the -g flag and no optimization for this to work. right?

Comment: @user1018562 glibc is normally built with `-O2 -g` flags. You should *not* be messing around with the flags.

Comment: Ok done that, but now it says "No line number known for mmap"

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some linker (ld) options which might help you. Look at the `ld` man page, --print-map, or --trace, or --trace-symbol should help you. Once you get the object file then you should be able to find the corresponding header file.